# If (system alert or 'ding!') then do something

Tags: macos, applescript

Is there any way to do something like:

If the application running dings with an error (like when you hit the wrong button in an application), then perform some task.

It's using a system sound, which makes me assume it must be calling the system in some way, so I'm wondering if I can capture that.

Hopefully I'm being clear.

The actual use case is that I want the script to move down a list in the application, counting the whole way down, then when it hits the bottom the applications goes BING because it can't go any further.  Once that occurs, then move on to the next task and save that number.

EDIT:  Here's an example of the application making the system error sound.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFE-FvyhqeA

I want it to go down the list, one by one, counting.  Then when it hits the bottom, and it dings, exit the loop.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to script a user interface of some sort. Have you already tried using accessibility scripting? That may be able to give you direct access to the contents of the table (or whatever it is); you probably don't need to resort to these crude methods.

Comment: Hmm, possibly.  It's possible I'm not familiar with this.  I'm posting a video for clarity...

Comment: Here's the example of the application, i scroll down.  then it hits the bottom and goes sets off the system error sound.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFE-FvyhqeA

Comment: Ah… I see, it's some sort of AV production application with a very custom-looking user interface. So accessibility may not be there, sorry. :(

Comment: Yeah, Avid editing software isn't know for playing nice with things, unfortunately.